# Azure Fault Domain Selection

Tags: azure, azure-availability-set

I have a requirement to create 7 VM in availability set and maximum 2 VM servers can be rebooted at a time.

I want to create 3 Fault domain and 4 upgrade domain.

[image]

some people suggest 2 FD and 4 UD. I do not agree with them. To create 3 FD will help when 2 racks would go down at least my 1VM will alive.

Am'I correct? If not please tell me why??

Comment: not a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go for 3 FD and 4 UD. The only problem - some regions do not support 3 FD.